# Bedeutung „es liegt mir nicht fern“

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet dieser Ausdruck:

> es liegt mir nicht fern, es zu tun

Bedeutet er, dass jemand die Absicht hat, etwas zu tun?

Comment: Zusätzlich zu den Antworten kann man noch anmerken, dass die verneinte Form "es liegt mir nicht fern" kein sehr üblicher Ausdruck ist. Jeder kennt die übliche Formel "Es liegt mir fern, zu ...", und nur daraus kann man ableiten, was mit der Verneinung wohl gemeint ist.

Comment: Vielen lieben Dank .. gut geklärt❤

Answer (score 2):

> bedeutet er, dass jemand die Absicht etwas zu tun hat?

Ja, genau das bedeutet er. Das ist eine ironisierende Verneinung von "es liegt mir fern ...", was soviel bedeutet wie "ich will nicht". Die Verneinung macht daraus ein "ich will nicht nicht", also "ich will".

Manchmal werden solche Sprachfiguren (man nennt die stilistisch motivierte doppelte Verneinung auch "Litotes") verwendet, um Ironie auszudrücken (zB "Ich bin nicht unerfreut" statt "Ich bin erfreut"), oder aber, um gewisse Einschränkungen in der Aussage zu machen. Zum Beispiel "ich bin nicht abgeneigt, ...", Das drückt entweder ein gewisses Zögern aus (will schon, aber nicht aus ganzem Herzen) oder es folgt etwas wie "aber nur, wenn ...".

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Hilfe.. das hab' ich schon mitbekommen

Answer (score 2):

Nein, nicht direkt. Es ist eine Aussage über wie wahrscheinlich es ist, eine Handlung durchzuführen.

Wenn etwas einem fern liegt, dann ist es eine Tätigkeit, die man nicht in Betracht zieht, weil ich Skrupel habe, weil ich sie nicht mag, oder aus sonstigen Gründen für mich nur unter großer Überwindung möglich ist.

Wenn einem folglich etwas *nicht* fern liegt, dann handelt es sich um eine Tätigkeit, die man durchführen könnte. Hingegen über eine (konkrete) Absicht desbezüglich sagt man nichts aus. Es ist nur ein Aussage über die Tätigkeit, dass man diese mit dem eigenen üblichen Verhalten und Moralvorstellungen einfach in Einklang bringen kann und es kaum Überwindung bedarf bzw. sogar sehr gerne durchgeführt würde.

Comment: Danke schön ganz detaliert❤❤

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe es ähnlich wie *planetmaker*.

Den Ausdruck würde ich mit »ich kann mir [gut] vorstellen, es zu tun« übersetzen, allenfalls mit »ich bin nahe daran/kurz davor, es zu tun«. Dass  jemand seine feste Absicht damit bekundet, halte ich für ein Gerücht. Der Ausdruck kann höchstens noch als Erklärung/Rechtfertigung einer schon ausgesprochenen Absicht dienen, das ist zumindest diskutabel:

> »Morgen trete ich dem Chef gegen die Autotür.«
> »Wie bitte? – Das kannst du doch nicht machen!«
> »Aber hallo. Es liegt mir nicht fern, es zu tun. So einer bin ich nun mal.«

Comment: Herzlichen Dank für die interessante Erklärung